# Best way to create a string in C and pass it down function to function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I want to create a string and pass it down function to function as it gets modified. I want to achieve this writing minimal code possible. What would be the best way to do this?

The snippet below is my take on this problem. It does compile, however, does not produce the expected result. I have defined the string in the function `stringA()`. The idea is `stringA()` will pass down function to function (i.e. `stringB()`, `stringC()`...) as it gets modified. `condition()` would always return 0 and it is just a use case if we need to make a conditional return.

```
static inline int condition(void)
{
#ifdef SIM
    return 1;
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}

const char *stringA(void)
{
    return condition() ? "." : "/mnt/mmcblk0p1";
}

static inline const char *stringB(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return condition() ? "" : buf;
}

void main()
{
      /* Pass 1 */
      char *str1 = strdup(stringB());
      printf("%s\n", str1); 

      /* Pass 2 */
      char *str2 = stringB();
      printf("%s\n", str2);

      /* Pass 3 */
      char str3[256];
      strcpy(str3, stringB());

      return;
}
```

**Further questions and feedbacks:**

1) *Pass 1* does not print anything. Why?

2) *Pass 2* does not print anything. Again why? I thought using `strdup()` would pass all the char pointers to `str2`.

3) *Pass 3* printed garbage (unwanted chars). Why? I chose not to use pointer. `strcpy()` did not seem to work.

4) I removed the `condition()` from the `return` statement and I got a seg fault. Why?

```
static inline const char *stringB(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return buf;
}
```

5) However, this approach below (I used arguments) seemed to print out "/mnt/mmcblk0p1/pathB" just fine. I am not sure how that worked when my other attempts failed. Any explanation? I am not particularly a big fan of this approach as it requires me to create needless arguments and create a needless `*buf` variable in `main()`

```
static inline const char *stringB(char *buf, int len)
{
    snprintf(buf, len, "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return condition() ? "" : buf;
}

void main()
{
      char *buf;
      char *str1 = strdup(stringB(buf, 128));
      printf("%s\n", str1); //It prints 
      return;
}
```

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable is a disaster waiting to happen.  (ie, `stringB` shouldn't return `buf`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell how to fix this. Please advise

Comment: @Sedmaister If you want to stack-allocate, the caller that uses the string needs to do the allocation, passing it down to callees for modification. Otherwise you can always return pointers to dynamically (or statically) allocated strings regardless of where you are in the call stack.

Comment: `stringB()` introduced undefined behaviour.  `buf` is of automatic storage duration, and ceases to exist when the function returns,

Answer (score 1):

```
static inline const char *stringB(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return condition() ? "" : buf;
}
```

basically you dont want to ever do this....
returning the buf here, is returning memory that is just on the stack and will be re-used by something else... maybe the calling function... at any rate it isn't your memory... you can return `""` that is a static char * and can't change...
if you want to return a string it will have to either be in a buffer that is passed into the function like:

```
static inline const char *stringB(char *buf, size_t len)
{
    snprintf(buf, len, "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return condition() ? "" : buf;
}
```

returning the buffer you just passed in doesn't make the most sense... but it is legal...

or malloced in the function;

```
static inline const char *stringB(void)
{
    char * buf = malloc(128);
    snprintf(buf, 128, "%s/pathB", stringA());
    return condition() ? "" : buf;
}
```

Comment: In this case, should I worry about freeing the malloc later on?

Comment: if you are mallocing it you should always return the buffer... and always free it... you shouldn't ever return `""` because that will crash, you can set `buf[0]='\0';` if condition and that will work as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

With...

```
static inline const char *stringB(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    ...
    return buf;
}
```

you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which's lifetime ends once the function `stringB` is left. Accessing this pointer then is undefined behaviour, and what you are observing is just that.

Just to try it out, write `static char buf[128];`, such that the buffer's lifetime exceeds that of the function execution. This is, however, not the best solution as it is not thread safe. Passing the destination to the function as you do with `stringB(char *buf, int len)` is better (though you should return `buf` in all code paths then).